# This for loop when I was trying to make a luck-based code has an error, how to fix?

Tags: tkinter, random

In my code, I am trying to make a luck-based code that I can test my luck.
But here, it says I have an error on my 'For', and it was pointing at the ':'
Please explain why, any help is appreciated

Here, I was doing my For loop

```
    for (count > 69420):
        num = random.randint(0,5000)
        print(num)
        if num == 69:
            root.mainloop()
```

In this line, it was saying error, so I was not able to run the code

```
    for (count > 69420):
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs debugging details, such as a [mre]. In addition there is no context provided that let us understand what the code is supposed to do and why OP had made decisions in the way he shows in the code.

Comment: Replace root.mainloop() to break Put the root.mainloop() at the bottom.

Comment: What is the error? SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `for (count > 69420):` is not valid in a for loop. You need an iterator and an iterable.

- If you want to count to 69420 and execute it once for each count,
  write: `for count in range(69420):`
- If you want to only execute it if count is higher, write: `if count > 69420:`
- If you want to only execute it while count is higher, write: `while count > 69420:` and
  don't forget to change the value of `count` within the loop or it
  will be infinite.

Also, there is no reason why you should make `root.mainloop()` conditional to chance. What exactly is your logic, there?